# The meaning and form of ' in most cases'

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is the phrase *in most cases*  a superlative prepositional phrase?

For example: *In most cases, I believe that community service is the best option.*

I'm trying to understand MFPA of this.

Comment: I googled MFPA. The biggest result was "mouth and foot painting artists".

Comment: Meaning Form Pronunciation Appropriacy

Comment: That phrase is as mysterious as 'MFPA'.

Comment: I have no idea but it is 100 percent idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

The word "most" is an adjective. It is the superlative form of "many".
[American Heritage Dictionary "most"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=most)

It can be used to modify many nouns. It doesn't need to be in a preposition phrase. For example,
`Most cars have wheels.`

In the given sentence,
`In most cases, I believe that community service is the best option.`
it means "in the greatest number of cases". That means that there are more cases where "community service is the best option" than cases where it is not the best option.

There aren't any "superlative prepositional phrases". In the preposition phrase "in most cases", the noun phrase "most cases" is the complement or object of the preposition "in". It consists of the noun "cases" and the superlative adjective "most".